# how to replace a string contains space with -

Tags: php

```
$url_name = str_replace(" ","-",$entry['department_name']);
$url_name = str_replace(" & ","-amp-",$entry['department_name']);
```

Hi iam replacing space with - using str_replace and using for loop to print all departments what if department name consists of something like that media & communication.for department having space it working fine but what if  it contains like media & communication.if i use both one is working the other is not working

Comment: is this the correct code? You're overwriting `$url_name` with the second line

Comment: Didn't even notice that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Put the amp replacement first.

```
$url_name = str_replace(" & ","-amp-",$entry['department_name']);
$url_name = str_replace(" ","-",$url_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? Note I'm using str_replace here with the search/replace args as arrays to save you doing multiple calls to `str_replace()`

```
$search = array(' & ', ' ');
$replace = array('-amp-', '-');
$url_name = str_replace($search, $replace, $entry['department_name']);
```

Comment: `$search = array(' ' => '-', '&' => 'amp'); $str = str_replace(array_keys($search), $search, $str);` is a bit more readable, as you can easily review and update replacements.