# PHP - Replace space between words with something

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to replace a string contains space with -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042802/how-to-replace-a-string-contains-space-with)

I want to replace blank space between words with something.

**Example, I have:**

```
$title = "An example title";
$separator = "*";
```

And I want a function which shows:

```
An*example*title
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `str_replace(' ','*',$title)`?

Comment: Should multiple spaces be replaced by multiple `*`, or a collapsed to a single `*`? (which determines whether str_replace() is appropriate)

Comment: Here is the google query for: "php replace character" https://www.google.nl/search?q=php+replace+character&oq=php+replace+character&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j59j62l2.3438&sugexp=chrome,mod=10&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 You are welcome.. it took me about 3 seconds to type.

Comment: `preg_replace('/\s+/', '*', $subject)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHPs [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) (str_replace — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string):

```
str_replace(" ","*",$title);
```

So, with your example:

```
$title = "An example title";
$separator = "*";
echo str_replace(" ", $separator, $title); // returns An*example*title
```

Comment: Thank you, I used:
$title = "An example title";
$separator = "*";
echo str_replace(" ", $separator,$title );

Answer (score 2):

You can also use regular expressions to replace several whitespace characters in a row with a selected string:

```
$str = 'this    is some     string';
$new_str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '*', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = "An example title";
$separator = "*";
$title = str_replace(' ',$separator,$title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
str_replace(" ","*",$title);
```